# Pandas: group by but showing missing value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Here's how the dataframe, df, looks like. I want to group by the position and to calculate the value in each group of level using the function I defined.

```
data

ID   Position   Level    Value
001     N         L         15
001     N         H         21
001     N         L         17
001     S         L         12
001     S         H         20
001     S         L         16
```

Here's how the function looks like

```
def rule(df):
    h_value = df.loc[df['level'] == 'H'], value]
    l_value = df.loc[df['level'] == 'L'], value].mean()

    df['dtm'] = h_value - l_value
    
    return df
```

Here's the groupby code.

```
new_df = df.groupby(['ID','Position']).apply(lambda x: rule(x))
```

but the result(new_df) shows

```
ID   Position   Level    Value     dtm     expected result of dtm
001     N         L         15     Nan              5
001     N         H         21      5               5
001     N         L         17     Nan              5
001     S         L         12     Nan              6
001     S         H         20      6               6
001     S         L         16     Nan              6
```

How can I fill the missing values with the same value of dtm in  each group of Position. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h_value = df.loc[df['Level'] == 'H', "Value"]` returns a `pd.Series`. The minus operation also returns a `Series` which would assign the value only by the `Index`.

To fix this, you can add `iat[0]`, i.e. `h_value = df.loc[df['Level'] == 'H', "Value"].iat[0]`, and the result would properly propagate.

```
   ID Position Level  Value  dtm
0   1        N     L     15  5.0
1   1        N     H     21  5.0
2   1        N     L     17  5.0
3   1        S     L     12  6.0
4   1        S     H     20  6.0
5   1        S     L     16  6.0
```